# How to remove HTML clone element

Tags: javascript, html

What I am trying to create is basically a close button for a cloned form.
The form along with the close button is generated onclick() using the following function:

```
$("#newVolton").click(function(){   
  var index = 0;
  $("#border").clone().attr('id', 'volton' + index).appendTo("#border");
  index++;
});
```

and I want to be able to close said form using the button that is generated alongside the specific instance of the form.

How should I got about deleting the instance?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You seem to append the clone to the source element

Comment: If the button is inside the form you want to close, you can get a reference to that form from the button's `.form` property.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to delegate

Make a main container and append to that
Then each div has its own HTML and a delete button.

Note I hide the first delete to allow the clone source to stay

You can change it to a template if you do not want to have an initial div

```js
$("#newVolton").on("click",function() {
  const $borders = $("#container").find(".border");
  const idx = $borders.length; // count the existing number of divs 
  $borders.eq(0).clone().attr('id', 'volton' + idx).appendTo("#container");
});
$("#container").on("click",".remove",function() { this.closest("div").remove() });
```

```css
#container>div.border span.remove {
  display: none
}

#container>div.border~div.border span.remove {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="newVolton">Add</button>
<div id="container">
  <div class="border" id="volton0">
    Some html <span class="remove">X</span>
  </div>
</div>
```